# Hi, i installed installed jupyter_to_medium python package and i can't activate it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, medium.com-publishing-api

i used "pip install jupyter_to_medium" to download install it and also used "jupyter bundlerextension enable --py jupyter_to_medium._bundler --sys-prefix" but and getting this error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json'".

(base) C:\Users\hp>pip install jupyter_to_medium
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting jupyter_to_medium
Using cached jupyter_to_medium-0.2.13-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2==3.0.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4<5.0.0,>=4.12.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (7.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0.0,>=1.24.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter_to_medium) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jinja2==3.0.3->jupyter_to_medium) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4<5.0.0,>=4.12.0->jupyter_to_medium) (2.3.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (6.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (6.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (6.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (7.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-nbextensions-configurator>=0.4.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-highlight-selected-word>=0.1.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (5.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-contrib-core>=0.3.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (4.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<4.0.0,>=3.7.1->jupyter_to_medium) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach!=5.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=5.7 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (5.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.4.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient>=0.5.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (0.5.13)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<4,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.2->jupyter_to_medium) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.2->jupyter_to_medium) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.2->jupyter_to_medium) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.2->jupyter_to_medium) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bleach!=5.0.0->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bleach!=5.0.0->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-contrib-core>=0.3.3->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (65.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (305.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-nbextensions-configurator>=0.4.0->jupyter-contrib-nbextensions<0.8.0,>=0.7.0->jupyter_to_medium) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=6.1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbclient>=0.5.0->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (7.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbclient>=0.5.0->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (1.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbformat>=5.7->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (2.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbformat>=5.7->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (4.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (23.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.8.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (21.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclassic>=0.4.7 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline>=0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: debugpy>=1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: comm>=0.1.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=7.23.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (8.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-widgets>=1.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit>=3.0.30 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (3.0.36)
Requirement already satisfied: qtpy>=2.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: stack-data in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat>=5.7->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (22.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat>=5.7->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.1.5->nbclient>=0.5.0->nbconvert<8.0.0,>=7.2.10->jupyter_to_medium) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook-shim>=0.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-server>=1.8 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit>=3.0.30->jupyter-console->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=1.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.3->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi-bindings in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio<4,>=3.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.58.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pure-eval in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: asttokens in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: executing in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio>=1.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from anyio<4,>=3.1.0->jupyter-server>=1.8->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.1->argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter_to_medium) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: jupyter_to_medium
Successfully installed jupyter_to_medium-0.2.13

I tried activating it below:

(base) C:\Users\hp>jupyter bundlerextension enable --py jupyter_to_medium._bundler --sys-prefix
Enabling jupyter_to_medium_bundler bundler jupyter_to_medium._bundler...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-bundlerextension-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 277, in launch_instance
return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 291, in start
super().start()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 266, in start
self.subapp.start()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 207, in start
self.toggle_bundler_python(self.extra_args[0])
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 196, in toggle_bundler_python
return toggle(module,
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 144, in enable_bundler_python
return _set_bundler_state_python(True, module, user, sys_prefix,
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 117, in _set_bundler_state_python
return [_set_bundler_state(name=bundler["name"],
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 117, in 
return [_set_bundler_state(name=bundler["name"],
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\bundler\bundlerextensions.py", line 76, in _set_bundler_state
cm.update(BUNDLER_SECTION, {
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\config_manager.py", line 130, in update
self.set(section_name, data)
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\config_manager.py", line 119, in set
f = open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json'

I tried uninstalling the package and reinstalling it back to no avail.

Comment: *PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied* you need to run your notebook as administrator

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).